# Get value between "," in HANA Database

Tags: database, hana, hana-sql-script

I have a column with the string "ItemBO:M101,1000129A,A"
I want to extract only the text "1000129A"

Many thanks in advance!

I tried using the function

```
SELECT SUBSTR_AFTER ('ItemBO:M101,1000129A,A',',') "substr after" FROM DUMMY;
```

but the result is 1000129A,A

Comment: … so you‘re just a substr_before(…) away from the desired result …

Answer (score 0):

Solved using

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_REGEXPR('[^,]+' IN 'ItemBO:M101,1000129A,A' FROM 1 OCCURRENCE 2) FROM DUMMY;
```